# UITableView snap to cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to implement is "snap to cell" effect in my `UITableView`. 
My `UITableView` has 3 equally sized cells, but for some reason the `UITableView` always snaps to cell 0 or cell 1 and doesn't ever snap to the third cell. its also wrong by about 50 points too low, no matter how hard you slide. I use the most obvious code to create the effect so I can't understand why it doesn't work.

```
- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset {
    NSIndexPath *pathForTargetTopCell = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.tableView.bounds), targetContentOffset->y)];
    DLog(@"indexPathForRow %d", pathForTargetTopCell.row);
    targetContentOffset->y = [self.tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:pathForTargetTopCell].origin.y;
}
```

Any thoughts about what could be going wrong?

EDIT:
I suspect this has something to do with the status bar and nav bar on top, since its off by exactly 64 points. Still doesn't explain why it doesn't recognise the last cell though..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the status bar offset, do this in your VC's `viewDidLoad`:

```
if([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setAutomaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets:)])
   [self setAutomaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets:NO];
```

**edit**

Just for testing, could you add 4 equally size cells and try snapping to the 3rd and 4th cells?

Modify your `scrollViewWillEndDragging` implementation as follows:

```
- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset {

    NSIndexPath *pathForCenterCell = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.tableView.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(self.tableView.bounds))];

    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:pathForCenterCell atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Added a 4th one, now it scrolls up to the third. Technically that would solve it, but that's really really hackish.

Comment: It does work! I have decided though to change my implementation so that it always "snaps" to the next cell in the order, according to the direction of the velocity. But for what I tried to achieve before this is accepted. This only works however if the size of your cells are close to the size of the screen.

Comment: it is enabling the paging effect. however, every cell is moving up for few pixels(ex:30px). how can I avoid that?